# How to tie the Build number with the Revit update in c#

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have revit build number got by OdBmBasicFileInfo::getSavedInVersion. But not getting how can i map it to build update version? Lik how can i convert 20210416_1515(x64) to 2019.2.3 as mentioned here https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-tie-the-Build-number-with-the-Revit-update.html.

Autodesk Revit forum

Answer (score 0):

The article that you point out on how to [How to tie the Build number with the Revit update](https://www.autodesk.com/support/technical/article/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-tie-the-Build-number-with-the-Revit-update.html) only lists the current officially supported versions, going back a couple of years. To implement support for older versions, I am afraid you are on your own and will have to assemble such a list yourself, e.g., manually and hard-coded. Please feel free to share your list here in this discussion thread, in case other encounter the same need. Thank you.